# maven sure fire plugin not honoring <groups> tag

Tags: junit, categories, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I want to distinguish my unit and integration test with help of @category in junit.
I have created two interface named UnitTest and IntegrationTests.
I am annotating my Test classes and test methods with @Category(UnitTest.class) and @Category(IntegrationTest.class).

I have configured a maven sure fire and maven fail safe plugins for my module.

The pom file looks something like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
 <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <name>My Parent Module</name>
 <properties>
  <skipTests>false</skipTests>
  <skipITs>true</skipITs>
 </properties>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
     <skipITs>${skipITs}</skipITs>
     <groups>com.myproject.IntegrationTest</groups>
     <includes>
      <include>**/*.java</include>
     </includes>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
      <phase>integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>integration-test</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>

    <configuration>
     <groups>com.myproject.UnitTest</groups>
     <excludedGroups>com.myproject.IntegrationTest</excludedGroups>
     <includes>
      <include>**/*.java</include>
     </includes>
     <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
     <systemProperties>
      <property>
       <name>targetURI</name>
       <value>${targetURI}</value>
      </property>
     </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

When I run mvn clean install  ( i expect unit tests (maven sure fire plugin) alone to run and integration tests (maven fail safe) to be skipped), which seems to be happening fine.

But,Strangely the maven sure fire plugin do not honor the   tag, I am ending up running tests will both @Category(UnitTest) and the ones without any
categories as well. However, Tests with @IntegrationTest are being skipped.

I thought all tests except with category @unitTests will be skipped.

I tried removing the com.myproject.IntegrationTest from the sure fire plugin configuration and  tests with @category (IntegrationTest.class) also started running.

Is this a bug in surefire plugin, As per documentation only tests with specified category should be ran.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to 2.12.1 (or later, the latest version is 2.15). 2.12 has the following bug:

[SUREFIRE-832: JUnit categories only work when junit47 provider is explicitly set](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-832)

If you can't upgrade, then explicitly specify the junit provider, see [Manually specifying a provider on page Using JUnit](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html).

Comment: 2.12.1,2.14.x, 2.15, with all the versions, i am facing the same problems, incliding the surefire-junit47 provider dependencies inside the plugin (explicitly) is not helping  as well :(